# EKS and kubectl running backplan 1.25 and kubectl 1.25 and cannot connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I created an EKS instance and am trying to connect via `kubectl` and keep getting the following error when trying to run any commands

```bash
kubectl version

#error 

error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

If I run

```bash
kubectl version --short --client 

#I get 

Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
```

looking at the documentation I can run plus or minus one minor release ie: running 1.25 kubectl version I should be able to connect to a backplane of 1.26 and 1.24

my cluster info is defined as
Kubernetes version
Info
1.25

I created the cluster under my root account "testing purposes only" and when I run

```bash
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

I get the correct identity back

I then run

````bash
aws eks --region us-west-2 update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster-name-here

and my ~/.kube/config file is updated correctly 

I'm don't have much hair left to pull out. 


users extact from config

the 111111111111 represents my aws accountid but removed for well..
the my-cluster-name-here represents where I have my real cluster name 

```bash

users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:111111111111:cluster/my-cluster-name-here
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - my-cluster-name-here 
      command: aws
````

the cluster entry entry for the cert authority data is present
the server is correct
and arn name is correct for the cluster in the ./kube/config file

I started with version 1.23 which worked once and when I tried again later kubectl was providing me the same error. I was able to switch my current context over to my azure AKS instance and it worked fine. was able to connect to my local k8ts running in docker desktop and worked fine.

I blew away the 1.23 environment in AWS and installed 1.24 which proved the same issue.
I blew away the 1.24 and did a clean install of 1.25. with each rev I was installing kubectl based on the aws docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-kubectl.html

Comment: Try changing it to from v1alpha1 to v1beta1

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is probably related to `awscli` and not `kubectl` itself. Please look at [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920#issuecomment-1445208236) thread. I remember that I have similar issue and upgrade of `awscli` resolved it.